# Is there a way to plot something iteratively so that the new plot overwrites the previous plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, visualization

What I want to do is to dynamically change a plot so that I can see it update as Python is executing its code.  Here is what I've come up with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

def plotResult(x,y):
    plt.plot(x,y)

plt.figure()

for i in range(5):
    x = [2,3,5*i]
    y = [1,2,3]
    plotResult(x,y)
    time.sleep(1)
```

What I want is for each call of "plotResult" to erase the previous plot with the new plot in its place.  What I end up with instead is each plot on top of each other.  I'm using time.sleep here because I want some time to look at the newly plotted result before it gets erased and replaced with a new plot.  I guess I'm essentially trying to create an animation here with each frame being a call to plotResult.

I'm going to do this for a code with a much longer execution time, so I don't want to have to wait until the code is done being executed to view the animation.  Please let me know if you know of a way to do this.

Comment: `plt.cla()` clears the axes. `plt.pause(0.1)` puts a 0.1 second pause.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest 
I added the plt.cla() statement to right before plt.plot, and the plt.pause(0.1) statement to right after plt.plot (both within the function plotResult(x,y), and now the plots do not appear on the same plot.  They instead show up on separate plots.

Comment: Forgot to say, you need to remove `time.sleep`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest
Thank you, I've done that, but it's the same result.

Comment: Where / how do you run this code? In which environment?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest
I am running my code with ipynb files in Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: In that case you would need to use the `%matplotlib notebook` or `%matplotlib widget` backend to achieve interactivity.

Answer (score 0):

Read about the [`FuncAnimation` class](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/animation_api.html). It repeatedly calls a function to update each frame of the animation.